# Checkbox in WPF datagridColumn not responding

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox

I have a WPF datagrid with column which includes checkboxes. I've noticed that if I perform quick check/uncheck between two checkboxes (20~30times) eventually one becomes non responsive even after some time has passed by. This checkbox is not disabled, but I just can't check and uncheck it. Any idea why it might be happening?

Comment: Can you provide some code? Any binding or event assigned to the `CheckBox` control?

Comment: the situation is quite simple, just plain wpf datagrid, no events in code behind

Comment: Debugging in VS or using released application?

Comment: This happens during debug....